# Is it possible to reverse escape string?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, netbeans, escaping

I know both NetBeans and Eclipse has options where if you paste multi-line, un-escaped string into a string variable, it will automatically add escape characters and add line breaks in. Is there a way to reverse the process?

For example:

```
function ShowHideOptions(trigger, element) {
 if( trigger ) {
    document.getElementById( element ).style.display = "";
 } else {
    document.getElementById( element ).style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

if pasted in to string becomes:

```
private static final String LABEL_JAVASCRIPT = "function ShowHideOptions(trigger, element) {\n"
            + " if( trigger ) {\n"
            + "     document.getElementById( element ).style.display = \"\";\n"
            + " } else {\n"
            + "     document.getElementById( element ).style.display = \"none\";\n"
            + " }\n"
            + "}";
```

I want reverse this process.

Comment: You can have your program print out LABEL_JAVASCRIPT

Comment: I dunno why I didn't think of that, LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question warrants another question. Why?

If you reverse this, the quotes would not be escaped and therefore you would get errors. Example:

```
System.out.println("System.out.println("Test");");
                                       ^
                          Error, everything after this quote is
                                    considered code
```

Notice the quotes aren't escaped. This code would generate an error where I marked it because the quotes apparently mean the string should end.

Also, if the newlines are reversed, this example:

```
System.out.println("test");
System.out.println("test2");
```

Would become:

```
System.out.println("test");System.out.println("test2");
```

The following code works fine. Please clarify the problem.

```
System.out.println(LABEL_JAVASCRIPT);
```

Comment: I had hacked some functionality by taking old html files and pasting them like that. Servelets then sent them as response. Now I need to go back for references sake. It's hard to edit them.

Comment: @Monir Why not `System.out.println(LABEL_JAVASCRIPT);`?

Comment: Yes, I followed Eric J's suggestion have my html files back. He suggested the same thing

Comment: Thanks guys for you help. It's been a very long day, time to go home.